# How can I do a text search with Express and Mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I am a trainee working on a school project. I am working on a REST API with Node, Express and Mongo.
So far I managed to do the whole CRUD but I want to improve my work a bit by adding text search. I want it to search the database and return only the results corresponding to my query param (not get all the collection's data and search it after).
So for example I have a user collection and I want to enable users to search friends by username.

I tried to add an index to my model or a 'text: true' item to the specific field I want to use as a  criteria for the search, in my model, as such:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 15,
    text: true
  },
...
```

Then I get my query text from the URL in my router and pass it to my controller function (it works, I console.logged it).

```
.get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (req.query.pseudo) {
        const searched = req.query.pseudo
        const usersSearched = getUsersByTextSearch(searched)
        return res.send(usersSearched)
      }
      const users = await getUsers()
      return res.send(users)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      return res.status(500).send(e.message)
    }
  })
```

Then I tried several things in my controller but I always get an empty object as a response:

```
const getUsersByTextSearch = async (search) => {
  const users = await User.find({
    $text:
    {
      $search: search,
      $language: 'fr',
      $caseSensitive: false
    }
  })
  return users
}
```

or

```
const getUsersByTextSearch = async (search) => {
  const users = await User.find({ pseudo: { $text: search, $options: 'i' } })
  return users
}
```

or

```
const getUsersByTextSearch = async (search) => {
  const users = await User.find({ pseudo: { $text: `${search}`, $options: 'i' } })
  return users
}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong with my code / if I am using the wrong tool ?

Answer (score 1):

```
let users = await User.find({
         pseudo: { $regex: `${search}`, $options: "i" } ,
    });
```

query searches for documents where the `pseudo` matches a regular expression pattern by considering the `search` variable with a case-insensitive option.

Comment: Hi, thanks! It improves my code a bit but I still get an empty object as a response.
I can console.log the text searched, but even if I copy-paste existing usernames it doesn't work. I don't get any error in the console.